# How to calculate time taken by perspective camera going from one to another position?

Tags: javascript, three.js

I have a perspective camera which is travelling across a spline curve.So I want to get the traveled time of the camera. total distance is calculated.what next?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the time at the beginning of your animation use:

```
var startTime = performance.now();
```

when your animation is finished use:

```
var endTime = performance.now();
```

and then

```
speed = distance / (endTime-startTime);
```

Comment: Thanks, I got it as requestanimationframe uses 60fps, so in 1 sec ~60points.with that i have something.Thanks again.

Comment: @Robun 60 fps is maximum. it depends on performance of your system.

Answer (score 0):

speed is distance/time, so if you know the distance and the desired speed, then time is distance/speed. Seems straightforward, but your question IS rather vague.

Comment: I know speed is distance/time but how calculate the speed of the camera.